# Angular - Dynamically instanciate a component, wait for its initialization and get its HTML

Tags: angular

I use an external dependency (ng2-table) to display a simple table that can be filtered and sorted.

The library accepts HTML strings as cell component. I would like to give the HTML of a component I use elsewhere in my app.

I tried to create the component with the ResolverComponentFactory, and to give the data the component need to populate the HTML, and then use the outerHTML as the HTML of the component.

```
const componentFactory = this._resolver.resolveComponentFactory(myComponent);
const component = componentFactory.create(this._injector); 
component.instance.data = data;

const cellContent = component.instance.myElementRef.nativeElement.outerHTML;
```

I thought I needed to wait for the ngContentInit hook, but as the component is not rendered the init does not append (event the ngOnInit one).

I know I could create the same string with a function but as I reuse the same template in different parts of my applications it would be really nice to be able to use that component.

I also know that I try to achieve something tricky and not very clean but I try to do the best compromise with what I have.

Comment: Have you found the the solution for case? Seems I face very similar issue.